# What are cases where a noun can be used as an adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

There are several threads about nouns as adjectives (adjectival nouns, nouns adjuncts), but I can't find a website or a post giving the rule of the uses of nouns as adjectives.

A history book.
A coffee cup.
A car park.
A gold ring.

Even on the Wikipedia's page, they explain the grammar, but not the rule that make a noun being usable as an adjunct in an expression.

For instance, in a *coffee cup*, "coffee" means that the cup is made for coffee. In a history book, that the book talks about history, a gold ring, that the ring is made of gold.

So, could I sum up the cases, to know when to use an adjunct, like this:

- Either when it's made of (gold ring)
- Or when it's the target/the aim (The park is for cars)
- Or when you can use "of", as a possession (The cell cycle)
- Or when it's the topic (history books), but isn't the aim too? A book to teach history?

Is it right, or are there other uses included in the rule?

Comment: Try googling **compound noun**

Comment: It's not about compound nouns, it's about the rule for using a noun as an adjective = the explanation of the use.

Comment: Nouns obviously cannot be adjectives, but they can be modifiers or complements, which I think is what you mean. For example, "a history book" (book about history) consists of the noun "history" as complement + the noun "book" as head. Incidentally, they are not compounds but syntactic constructions (modifier/complement + head).

Comment: They can be "used as adjectives". Wikipedia and manylinguistics books use this expression, so I think there's nothing wrong about it. My question is what makes "history" and the other adjuncts (it's the term) usable as adjectives (modifiers if you prefer)? What is the rule and their common trait?

Comment: @Quidam Actually, it *is* about compound nouns. Compounds are formed when two words are joined together. In this case, one noun is joined to another noun. The noun on the left is acting as if it's an adjective. (It's also called an attributive noun.) The first noun modifies the second noun—forming a compound noun. Compound nouns don't even need to come from two nouns originally. Just look at *ice cream*, which started off as *iced cream*.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know if they are called compound, they are called noun adjuncts, or adjectival nouns in the books I read.